# Is L closed under linear-time reductions?

Tags: complexity-theory, reductions, complexity-classes, space-complexity

L is as usual the complexity class DSPACE($\log n$), of languages decidable using a deterministic Turing machine using logarithmic workspace.

> Is L closed under linear-time reductions?

It is possible that for some pair of languages Q and R, every linear-time reduction from Q to R requires more than logarithmic space.
Up to linear space could be used while still remaining within linear time.
So it isn't immediately obvious to me that L must be closed under linear-time reductions.

On the other hand, it is not clear what a counterexample would look like.
One wants a language Q that can be linear-time many-one reduced to a language in L (for instance, to undirected graph st-connectivity), yet so that Q is not in L.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

L is closed under linear-time reductions if and only if ​L = P.

**Proof:**

If L is closed under linear-time many-one reductions then:

Since L has non-trivial problems, all problems that are solvable linear time are in L.

Let (x) be the modification of [the most basic P-complete problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-complete#P-complete_problems) to ask about "the first sqrt(T) steps" rather than "the first T steps". ​Since unary-to-binary conversion can be done in linear time and [[square-roots can be computed](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1004.3412v2.pdf#page=10) and [TMs can be simulated](http://www.cs.duke.edu/~reif/courses/complectures/Arora/lec3.pdf) in [quasi-linear time](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:Q#ql)], (x) can be solved in linear time. ​Since L has non-trivial problems, there is a linear-time many-one reduction from (x) to a problem in L. ​By this paragraph's assumption, that means (x) is in L.  Since L can square unary inputs, there is a logspace reduction from [the most basic P-complete problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-complete#P-complete_problems) to (x). ​Thus (x) is P-complete. ​Since (x) is in L, that means ​ P ⊆ L .

If L is closed under linear-time many-one reductions then then ​P ⊆ L. With no assumptions, L ⊆ P. ​ Therefore, if L is closed under linear-time many-one reductions then then​ L = P. Since P can perform linear-time Turing reductions, P is closed under linear-time Turing reductions. Therefore, if ​L = P  then L is closed under linear-time Turing reductions. ​ QED

Comment: Thanks!  That turned out to be more subtle than I anticipated.